# DeclarativeContent - wait to show page action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm brand new to Chrome Extensions, but I'm trying to figure out how to delay showing a `page action` icon until I'm ready for it to.

I have a content script (which waits to execute until the DOM is ready) and all is does is grab a URL from the page.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"url": getUrl()});

function getUrl() {
  var url = $('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').attr('content');
  return url;
}
```

In my background.js page I use `declarativeContent` to see if the page action should be displayed. This is very similar, if not identical to the Google example.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule1]);
  });
});


var rule1 = {
  conditions: [
    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { urlContains: 'www.example.com', schemes: ['http', 'https'] }
    })
  ],
  actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
};
```

I have a listener set up to get the message sent from the `content_script`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    url =request.url; //set global variable in background.js so I have it
    sendResponse({});
});
```

And finally, I have the action when the page action is clicked.

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  alert(url);
});
```

This code works. However, if I press the page_action button too early during the page load, I'll get an `undefined` alert because the page action is displayed/available before the content script is executed and the message is passed.

How can I delay showing the page action icon until the content script has been executed and the url is set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use a content script to get the URL of the tab. Simply use `tab.url` (where `tab` is the first argument received by the `chrome.pageAction.onClicked` event) to get the page's URL:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  alert(tab.url);
});
```

If the usefulness of the page action ico *really* depends on the page state that can only be obtained in the content script, then don't use the [`chrome.declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API, but call [`chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show;) instead:

```
var url;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    url = request.url; // Save some state
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, after reading your answer I think it's my code that's confusing. In the content script, I'm not getting the URL of the tab - rather I'm getting a URL embedded in the page (`<meta itemprop='contentUrl' content="..."`) that the content script is running on.

I'm passing that back to the `background.js` page so I can then manipulate it

Comment: @joshft91 Read the bottom of my answer for that use case.